# Batch File - Delete a File only if another file exists

Tags: batch-file

I wish to create a Batch file that can do the following:

If "File 1abc (X).bin" exists then delete "File 1abc (Y).bin", if not, then keep "File 1abc (Y).bin" and move on.

Basically there are usually multiple versions of a file where one kind (marked by a single variable in the filename that always stays the same) is superior to the other. If that superior version however does NOT exist, i wish the inferior version to remain.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please provide any code you have tried so far, and also add some example data to your question for clarification...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IF statement (http://www.computerhope.com/if.htm):

```
IF EXIST File1.ext DEL File2.ext
```

UPDATE - To address the specific problem mentioned in the question:

```
set FileNames="File 1abc (*).bin"
set LastVersion=""
:: Find last version
for %%f in (%FileNames%) do (
    if "%%f" GTR %LastVersion% SET LastVersion="%%f"
)
:: Delete old versions
for %%f in (%FileNames%) do (
    if "%%f" LSS %LastVersion% DEL "%%f"
)
```

There is one catch: if the version (X or Y in your example) is a number, it should be specified with a fixed number of digits (e.g. (009), (010), ...), because (9) is considered greater than (10).

Comment: Would that not require that i name every single file? Wouldnt it be much faster then to just do it by hand?

Comment: This works well for the problem in the title, but not the problem described in the actual question. You're going to need a `for /f` loop for this.

Comment: How is such a thing done exactly? This concept is new to me.

Comment: Oh, right. I did not realize that the last paragraph of the question made things more complicated...

Comment: I am sorry. Its my fault really. I still dont know how to compress my idea into a cohesive topic-head that expresses the full concept.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can tell me if this is closer to what you want.